# Mac OS X Yosemite strange Jira folder in Users

Tags: macos, user-accounts, osx-yosemite

I have found recently a strange **Jira** item in my Users folder:

[image]

This folder had permissions: System - read & write, everyone - no access.

And after I have added myself to permissions I have found the following content inside:

[image]

What is this folder for? Should I worry about it? Can I delete it?

P.S.I do not use and I have never installed [this Jira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIRA) on my mac. I do not have a user named Jira in "Users & Groups" settings. I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.

Comment: What user is the folder owned by?  You should take ownership of the folder, after you determine who the owner is, and verify the contents.

Comment: Permisions are: System - read & write, Everyone - No Access.

Comment: Do you use Stash or BitBucket? or any other Atlasssian tools?

Comment: @MrWonderful I am using BitBucket via web and I have SourceTree installed.

Comment: Then I'd guess it was created by one/both of those.  I'd leave it -- it probably isn't taking much space (as a guess.)  You could also email support at Atlassian to double-check.  Sorry about the typo in the last comment... my autocorrect put 3 's's in their name! :-/